# Search formula for best text match among two excel lists

Tags: excel

I have a long list of products (+20,000 items) of surgical instruments. Sometimes I receive requests for different names of these products which is impossible to manually match in my list.

I was thinking of a formula to find or suggest the closest result of match for the common words in each cell.

I have created this formula:

```
=INDEX('Products'!G:G,MATCH((("*"&LEFT(A2,5),'Products'!G:G,0))
```

(where Products G:G refers to my long list.

it gave some results correctly but more than 80% of the result came back with false results.

please see the attached image to show you the result.

is there is a way I can get more accurate result?

or I was thinking of finding major category of each item such as:

- Category 1: Scissors, Retractors, Knives, etc.
- Category 2: Straight, Curved, Angeled, etc.
- Category 3: Sharp, Blunt, etc.
- Category 4: 10mm, 130mm, 24cm, etc. (size)

which is easy for me to do it.

then use the same formula but with referring to the common words..
something like:

```
=INDEX(Products!G:G,MATCH("*"&LEFT(E2,5)&"*"&F2&"*"&G2&"*",Products!G:G,0))
```

where E2, F2, G2 refers to the categories..
I tried but it gave false results as well.

[image: Search Formula]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I urge you in the strongest sense of the word to spend some time creating a good quality master table and then spinning off 1 table for each category.

make use of clean(), trim(), proper(), heck, if you need to copy the data in notepad++ and enable view all symbols then switch between ansi utf utf8 wtf omgwtf or any other encoding to ensure you dont have any hidden special characters than do it.

you have 4 categories, so that's 4 1 column tables.  name them.  no duplicates.  no trash. no junk. sort your data. nice clean names/words/whatever you categorize by. if you absolutely must add an index or key column then go ahead but do yourself a favor and stop there.  use a different table to deepen your relationships.

next step is to to create comboboxes. i'm not sure why but the combobox in excel is not the same combobox in the vba editor.  you want the one in the editor. you can make a fancy user form or you can make a minimalist text box design. whatever you fancy.   just make sure the combobox has a field for RowSource in the properties.  for whatever reason i don't get that option if i am not in the vba editor when i create the box.

you're almost gauratneed to want drawmodal = false on every user form you make for these boxes

you probably really don't need more than 4 boxes but it depends what you're doing so that's up to you.  name your combo boxes.

verify each box has: matchentry = 1-fmMatchEntryComplete
i recommend: style = 0 - fmStyleDropDownCombo
this will allow you to begin typing and autocomplete the first match and also let you select from a drop down list, starting with the the first match of the name you've typed.
you can set the number of elements in the list.  default is 8.  if you have a slow computer than i wouldn't push it much.  if you have a best then give it a shot.
you can also change fonts for easier reading and a bunch of other format changes.

now the this is the most important part - RowSource will be one of those 4 tables

now that i've given instructions, let me explain why.  some businesses don't have the best practices and i'm currently with one that's using an oracle erp solution for data management but the front end isn't used.  data entry is done in excel and loaded into oracle using batches.  lookups in oracle continue to be a psychological barrier for the ap/ar teams so i did exactly what i suggested here but took it a few steps farther.

i pulled the vendor master and i pulled teh customer master
i cleaned the data and compiles simple pure clean 1 column tables
then i created a form for the comboboxes

first came ap with vendor name
then vendor number
then vendor remittance location
our orderering facility number

selecting a vendor name populates the vendor number box with the possible vendor numbers.  same for remittance location and ordering facility

i pulled a year's worth of transaction data and created a gl table.  some vendors have only ever used 1 gl acount.  some several. there's a % number next to each gl. that represents the value of transactions posted from that vendor to that gl for the last year.

next up a date picker and text boxes for invoice fields.
get it nice and tight on a form, set the tab stops, add a commit button and all of a sudden we have a front end excel platform that performs better than oracle - because people use

i haven't finished the ar side but it'll get done and i'll the angels will be rejoicing and singing my name for years to come.

1:1 matching with autofill and drop down functionality you can't beat it.  that's what you get with my suggestion.

best of luck!

Comment: It occurs to me that I didn't answer your question.  I only scratched the surface of one side of the problem.  I'll be baaaaacck.  After 10 hours of slaving over a different spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your comprehensive answer.. that was great suggestion that I will start working on it right away.. thanks  again for your time :)